# Salt - Installed memcached formula via github, but cp.list_master doesnt show any memcached

Tags: salt-stack

I have run `apt-get install python-git-doc` and `apt install python-is-python3 python3-git` to install python-git

And I have edited my `/etc/salt/master` file, so it now looks like this:

```yaml
fileserver_backend:
  - git
  - roots
```

```yaml
gitfs_remotes:
  - https://github.com/saltstack-formulas/memcached-formula.git
```

I restart my `salt-master` using `systemctl restart salt-master`.

Yet when I run `salt x_minion cp.list_master` my output generates with no errors but I don't have any memcached files
(x_minion I just made up to not have my data here, its just a fake name for my minion)

```yaml
# salt myminion cp.list_master
myminion:
  - .git/HEAD
  - .git/config
  - .git/description
  - .git/hooks/applypatch-msg.sample
  - .git/hooks/commit-msg.sample
  - .git/hooks/fsmonitor-watchment.sample
  - .git/hooks/post-update.sample
  - .git/hooks/pre-applypatch.sample
  - .git/hooks/pre-commit.sample
  - .git/hooks/pre-merge-commit.sample
  - .git/hooks/pre-push.sample
  - .git/hooks/pre-rebase.sample
  - .git/hooks/pre-receive.sample
  - .git/hooks/prepare-commit-msg.sample
  - .git/hooks/update.sample
  - .git/info/exclude
  - apache.sls.save
  - apache.sls.save.1
  - apache/init.sls
  - apache/map.sls
  - apache/mods.sls
  - apache/welcome.sls
  - mods.sls.save
  - show_content.sls
  - top.sls
```

Am I missing a step to correctly install the memcached formula?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `fileserver_backend` should be `gitfs`, not `git`.

Aside from that, you are missing a step of mapping the saltenvs for the formula. As that repo has no tags, you're stuck with pinning by commit. Excluding the top level folder is also a good idea:

```yaml
gitfs_remotes:
  - https://github.com/saltstack-formulas/memcached-formula.git:
    - all_saltenvs: ba7fdda
    - root: memcached
    - mountpoint: salt://memcached
```

Also note that you appear to have a git repo and various temporary files in your file root, which you are exposing to all minions.

Comment: This does the same as what I said. It doesn't give any errors but doesn't list any Memcached files

Comment: You fixed the `fileserver_backend` and restarted the master and checked it was up to date with `salt-run fileserver.update`?

Comment: Yes, I changed the fileserver_backend and still the same result.
When I run `salt-run fileserver.update` I get `[CRITICAL] No suitable gitfs provider module is installed.
True`

Comment: Then you haven't installed either `gitpython` or `pygit2` into Salt's environment.

Comment: I have pygit2 installed

Comment: Not in Salt's environment you don't. Confirm with `salt --versions`.

Comment: I'm confused then, I have installed pygit2, is there something special I have to do to link it to salt? It says `pygit2: Not Installed` so it's not linked to salt

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS

Comment: I assume you're using a onedir package? You need to use e.g. `salt-pip` to install it.

Comment: amzing! `salt-pip install pygit2` linked pygit2 to my salt.
After running `salt-run fileserver.update` and `systemctl restart salt-master` (just in case). When I now run the command `salt myminion dan_minion cp.list_master` the `memcached` files now appear

Comment: It doesn't "link" it, it installs it.